# Olympus Camera Kit: Cannot update exposure compensation value soon after

Tags: ios, swift, olympus-air, olympus-camerakit

I have HDR app that takes three pictures with different exposure compensation settings, but I cannot change exposure compensation value shortly after shooting. Are there any restrictions on update timing of property?

---

```
for var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ {
    switch i {
        case 0:
                camera.setCameraPropertyValue("EXPREV", value: "<EXPREV/+2.0>", error: nil)
        case 1:
                camera.setCameraPropertyValue("EXPREV", value: "<EXPREV/0.0>", error: nil)
        case 2:
                camera.setCameraPropertyValue("EXPREV", value: "<EXPREV/-2.0>", error: nil)
        default:
                camera.setCameraPropertyValue("EXPREV", value: "<EXPREV/0.0>", error: nil)
    }

    camera.takePicture( nil, 
            progressHandler: nil, 
            completionHandler:{ info -> Void in dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)},              
            errorHandler: {error -> Void in dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)} )

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```

Comment: What does he manual say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change any camera property while the camera accesses to the memory card. Please check if `mediaBusy` is false before you update the camera property.

Try to insert the code below after the last `semaphore_wait()`.

```
while camera.mediaBusy {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.2)
}
```